# jQuery live() function for purpose of heavy ajax use of site

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, live

Ive been looking for a way to make sure all scripts are triggered accordingly as content is loaded in and out of the page via jQuery load.

The best method so far is the live function but I cannot get it to trigger functions on load, only operate with elements loaded in.

EG.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').live('keyup',function(){
        $(this).innerHeight(20 + (16 * ($(this).prop('scrollHeight') / $(this).css('line-height').replace('px', '') - 1.25)));
    });
    $('textarea').trigger('keyup');
});
```

This will make the textarea perform correctly on the keyup function but will not trigger the initial `$('textarea').keyup();`

How would I do that / is there a better way of achieving what I am after.`

I have got this far but my initial call does not work once the page has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', 'textarea',function(){
        $(this).innerHeight(20 + (16 * ($(this).prop('scrollHeight') / $(this).css('line-height').replace('px', '') - 1.25)));
    });
    $('textarea').trigger('keyup');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you want to use `trigger()` to fire an event.

Also, don't use `live()` because it's deprecated. Instead use `on()`. The syntax slightly changes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', 'textarea', function(){
        $(this).innerHeight(20 + (16 * ($(this).prop('scrollHeight') / $(this).css('line-height').replace('px', '') - 1.25)));
    });
    $('textarea').trigger('keyup');
});
```

The selector in `$(document).on('keyup', 'textarea', function)` works as follows:

1. Look for elements in `document` that are matching `textarea` (this also works for elements that are added after page load)
2. If the `keyup` event is triggered, execute the callback method

Therefore, you can write something more specific than `document` to decrease the computation time. For example:

```
$('#myForm').on('keyup', 'textarea', function)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alp's response works perfectly.  The handler fires when you use `trigger()` so I don't understand where you're getting your error.

Be sure that you trigger the keyup on your textarea **AFTER** you have loaded whatever dynamic content you are populating it with.  If you are using jQuery's `load()` to bring in content, trigger the keyup in the callback function.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/illnuget/SqR4Z/37/)